# How to print something on the screen after clicking with a mouse on some object?

Tags: java, mouseevent, paintcomponent, mouselistener

So I've been trying to print line after clicking with a mouse on some object that I have previously painted on the screen with mouseClicked method. I'm drawing elements from an arrayList filled with drawable elements. Here is my code:

```
ShapeSh s = new VertexG(x,y,Window.graph2);
    ((VertexG) s).addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            ShapeSh z = (VertexG)e.getSource();
            System.out.println("some text");
        }
    });
```

No "some text" is printed. What am I doing wrong? :( This is how I am drawing elements from the array:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(ShapeSh shape: drawingList){
        shape.drawThis(g);
    }
}

public void drawThis(Graphics g){       

    g.setColor(c);
    g.fillOval(x,y,2*radius,2*radius);
    g.setFont(f);
    g.setColor(c2);
    g.drawString(value, x-8, y-8);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when clicking mouse, try this mehtond "mousePressed(MouseEvent e)" instead of "mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)"

Have a try this one. A private MouseClickListener.

```
private class MapMouseClickListener implements MouseInputListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        int clickButtonType = e.getButton();
        // BUTTON3 is the right mouse button.
        if (clickButtonType == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            System.out.println("some text");// and whatever you want to active.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: It's still not working :( The objects are being drawn on the JPanel attached to JFrame, but when I try to click on that object or enter it with my mouse, nothing is hapenning :/ I replaced my "new MouseAdapter(){.." with your "new MapMouseClickListener()". Maybe I should do this diffrently? please help

Comment: make sure your JPanel has added in your JFrame.  could you show more code in the question?